# Boolean(data type not class) Size in Java

Tags: java, boolean, primitive-types

I have read that boolean doesn't take any memory size from java 5 & above.Why Boolean do not take any size in memory (not even single bit) from Java 1.5 and above? for e.g.

```
boolean flag=true;
```

it should only take 1 bit because you can use 1 to represent the value `true`, right?

so what is the core concept behind it?

Comment: If you can specify where, for example, you read this, or quote the specifics to explain why the general answer isn't sufficient, we can reopen the question.

Comment: That’s not correct. I’m sure that this statement has been taken out of context. There are situations where you can process a boolean state without needing memory to store it, but that’s not always the case. And it’s not specific to Java 5.